# Multi-line batch script converted to single line command returns different results than the original

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I'm trying to transform the multi-line script

```
@echo off

for /f "eol=: delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad *^|sort /r') do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for %%F in (*) do move "%%F" "..\%%~nxD - %%F" >nul
  popd
  rd /s /q "%%D"
)
exit
```

to a single line in order to register it as a context menu entry. To my understanding, the equivalent single line command would be this one:

```
@echo off && for /f "eol=: delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad *^|sort /r') do (pushd "%%D" && for %%F in (*) do move "%%F" "..\%%~nxD - %%F" >nul && popd && rd /s /q "%%D") && exit
```

...but it produces different results than the original script.

Replacing && with & produces a third different result but as far as I know I would still need the && anyway in this case.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: This is merely a guess, but `&&` means only run the command if the previous was successful.  There might be moves that are failing in the inner loop?  You can use just `&` to string the commands together.

Comment: Tried that already as well but it didn't work either. It does make sense to wait for the previous command to end, though. As far as I know, each line break acts as a && in that sense so it should be fundamentally the same. I'm proven wrong though, so I've had to ask.

Comment: alternatively, you might be able to save this to a batch file and have your context menu entry call the batch script.

Comment: That's the backup plan but I'd rather be able to avoid unnecessary files and absolute paths.

Comment: (1) `&` probably is the right way to separate commands that were on sequential (separate) lines in the multi-line script.  (2) Can you describe the way the results change between the different permutations of the code?  (3) How are you running the one-line version?  Do you still have it in a `.BAT` file, or are you already trying to plug it into the registry?  (3b) If you're running it some way other than in a `.BAT` file, have you tried changing `%%` to `%`?  Also — and this is just a WAG — I wonder whether quoting is an issue.

Comment: I wonder if the opening and closing parenthesis of the `DO` portion of the FOR loop aren't happy with being separated by `&&`. Also, the opening echo off and final exit statements are probably unnecessary.

Comment: @Twisty: I believe that (the first part of) your comment isn’t right, but it gave me an idea of something to look at that led to my answer, below.  So thanks for the collaboration!

Comment: @G-Man excellent! Yes, I was only "wondering" because I didn't know if it was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `for … do` is “greedy”. 
(I don’t remember knowing this before,
and it doesn’t seem to be prominently documented in `for /?`.)

Here’s what I mean:

Consider script `cow1.bat`:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (how now brown) do echo %%a
echo cow
```

Pretty trivial. 
When run, it outputs

```
how
now
brown
cow
```

as we might guess.

Consider script `cow2.bat`:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (how now brown) do echo %%a & echo cow
```

The same, except lines 2 and 3 have been joined, delimited by a `&`. 
Guess what!? 
When run, it outputs

```
how
cow
now
cow
brown
cow
```

It’s being interpreted as if it were

```
@echo off
for %%a in (how now brown) do (echo %%a & echo cow)
```

(Changing `&` to `&&` didn’t have any effect.) 
In a (to me) bigger surprise,

```
@echo off
for %%a in (how now brown) do (echo %%a) & echo cow
```

*also* functioned the same as `cow2`. 
I had to use

```
@echo off
(for %%a in (how now brown) do echo %%a) & echo cow
```

to get the original, `cow1` behavior.

---

### How does this affect the OP?

```
for %%F in (*) do move "%%F" "..\%%~nxD - %%F" >nul && popd && rd /s /q "%%D"
```

is analogous to `cow2`: 
If `%%D` (the directory we just `pushd`’ed into) is `beatles`,
then the above code segment does this:

```
move "george" "..\beatles - george" >nul    &&    popd    &&    rd /s /q "beatles"
move "john"   "..\beatles - john"   >nul    &&    popd    &&    rd /s /q "beatles"
move "paul"   "..\beatles - paul"   >nul    &&    popd    &&    rd /s /q "beatles"
move "ringo"  "..\beatles - ringo"  >nul    &&    popd    &&    rd /s /q "beatles"
```

(whitespace added for clarity). 
So it’s moving the first file (`george`),
and then `popd`’ing out of the `beatles` directory and deleting it,
leaving the other files to be reaped by the roomba.

### Recommendation (TL;DR)

Try

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%D in ('dir /b /s /ad *^|sort /r') do (pushd "%%D" && (for %%F in (*) do move "%%F" "..\%%~nxD - %%F" >nul) && popd && rd /s /q "%%D")
                                                                              ↑                                                   ↑
```

#### Trivial question:

Why do we need the `*` in the `dir /b /s /ad *` subcommand?

Comment: I won't use this as an excuse but I got this script by request as so far I've been unable to find where to learn batch from so I'm afraid I can't answer that question. I'd really like to learn or at the very least understand the code I'm given but it's rendered pointless without the base knowledge I'm missing.

Comment: "Why do we need the `*` in the `dir /b /s /ad *` subcommand?" You don't.

Comment: @JesúsCruz: Well, try running `dir /b /s /ad *` and `dir /b /s /ad` at various times, in various places, situations and contexts.  If they always produce the same output, you may become confident that David and I are correct, and that they are equivalent. If you're bold, you can delete the superfluous two characters from your script. On the other hand, if you ever get different outputs from the two commands, please come back here and let us know, because then you will have taught us something.

Comment: I will remove it and see if anything stops working. One more question, even if a bit off-topic (I don't know if it's worth opening a new topic): the script doesn't work with folders with ' on their filenames. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually, now that I've removed the * the script works with single quote characters in filenames. Thank you for everything.